Spring boot - Event hub - non-nullable field authBytes was serialized as null - Standard plan - Kafka
I am getting an error when sending messages from local machine to Event Hub Kafka
The hub is standard tier and see Kafka enabled

So this stackoverflow post is not working for my scenario -  stackoverflow
Source : Microsoft documenatation - eventhub
application.properties
spring.cloud.function.definition=consume;supply
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consume-in-0.destination=shub
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consume-in-0.group=$Default
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.supply-out-0.destination=shub
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=stsgdjhsacy.servicebus.windows.net:9093

My pom
    <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud-azure.version>5.12.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-binder</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Stacktrace

2024-05-29T18:41:51.075+01:00  INFO 21320 --- [hubproducer]
[onPool-worker-2] c.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential  : Azure
Identity => Attempted credential AzureDeveloperCliCredential returns a
token 2024-05-29T18:41:51.109+01:00  INFO 21320 --- [hubproducer] [
main] .o.i.e.ExpiringCredentialRefreshingLogin : Successfully logged
in.
2024-05-29T18:41:52.411+01:00  WARN 21320 --- [hubproducer] [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Unexpected error from sto....cy.servicebus.windows.net/266.066.142.1954 (channelId=-1); closing connection
java.lang.RuntimeException: non-nullable field authBytes was
serialized as null    at
org.apache.kafka.common.message.SaslAuthenticateResponseData.read(SaslAuthenticateResponseData.java:137)
~[kafka-clients-3.6.2.jar:na]     at
org.apache.kafka.common.message.SaslAuthenticateResponseData.(SaslAuthenticateResponseData.java:86)
~[kafka-clients-3.6.2.jar:na]     at
org.apache.kafka.common.requests.SaslAuthenticateResponse.parse(SaslAuthenticateResponse.java:81)
~[kafka-clients-3.6.2.jar:na]     at
org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractResponse.parseResponse(AbstractResponse.java:187)
~[kafka-clients-3.6.2.jar:na]

I am not sure, if the dependencies are correct.
Any idea on how to resolve ?

Check the user's application.properties and pom.xml files to ensure that the dependencies are correct.

I have posted what you asked in the question

I want to install kafka-ui to my cluster and I've the same issue and the same stacktrace.
